# PowerShell run exe file and pass args as string var

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a power shall scrip to run exe file with arguments. The list of args are constructed in a way that if value of the arg is empty or null, the parameter shall not be passed

Below is my script

```
 $runnerCommand = " "
[string]$splitRun = "20:1"
[string]$maxTestWorkers = "777"
[string]$retryTimes = "9"
[string]$testFilterInXmlFormat = "<filter><cat>XX</cat></filter>"

#$runnerCommand += '--testDllPath ' + $testDllPath + " "

if ($splitRun){
    $runnerCommand+= "--splitRun '$splitRun' "
}

if ($maxTestWorkers){
    $runnerCommand+= "--maxTestWorkers '$maxTestWorkers' "
}

if ($retryTimes){
    $runnerCommand+= "--retryTimes '$retryTimes' "
}

if ($testFilterInXmlFormat){
    $runnerCommand+= "--testFilterInXmlFormat '$testFilterInXmlFormat' "
}


$cmdPath = "C:\AutoTests\TestAutomation.Runner\bin\Debug\TestAutomation.Runner.exe"


& $cmdPath --testDllPath C:/AutoTests/Build/TestAutomation.TestsGUI.dll $runnerCommand
```

It looks like that PowerShell do a 'new line' before $runnerCommand in the last line of code that results in not passing the args from $runnerCommand

Please suggest how to solve the problem.

I tried different approaches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're currently passing all of the arguments as a single string. You should instead use an array with each argument as a separate element. I can't actually test this, but something like this should work:

```
[string]$splitRun = "20:1"
[string]$maxTestWorkers = "777"
[string]$retryTimes = "9"
[string]$testFilterInXmlFormat = "<filter><cat>XX</cat></filter>"

$runnerArgs = @(
    '--testDllPath', 'C:/AutoTests/Build/TestAutomation.TestsGUI.dll'
    if ($splitRun) {
        '--splitRun', $splitRun
    }
    if ($maxTestWorkers) {
        '--maxTestWorkers', $maxTestWorkers
    }
    if ($retryTimes) {
        '--retryTimes', $retryTimes
    }
    if ($testFilterInXmlFormat) {
        '--testFilterInXmlFormat', $testFilterInXmlFormat
    }
)

$cmdPath = "C:\AutoTests\TestAutomation.Runner\bin\Debug\TestAutomation.Runner.exe"

& $cmdPath $runnerArgs
```

Note that PowerShell allows expressions, including `if`-expressions, inside the array sub-expression operator (`@()`).

Comment: Nice solution! To be precise `@()` is not the [array initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.3#creating-and-initializing-an-array), which would be `,`. It is the [array sub-expression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#array-subexpression-operator--).

Comment: Thanks. This works like a charm. I got where the problem was!